# entity framework and LINQ - Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: linq, entity-framework, odp.net

I'm recieving the error

> Arithmetic operation resulted in overflow.

when running this:

```
using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    var OraLINQEX1 = from e in ctx.TABLE_A
        select e;
    Console.WriteLine("LINQ to Entities Result");
    foreach (var result in OraLINQEX1)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ID: {0}    Name: {1}", result.FIELDA,           result.FIELDB));
    }
}
```

My database is Oracle, I'm using [this reference](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm).

I used another table and it worked. My table has many fields. The fields are varchar2 and number without size.

I know the exact record of table that generetes the error, but I don´t know how to get a more detailed message.

Please, help me.

Comment: Is the error a SQL exception or is it happening in .NET? Also, are the numbers in the database too large to fit inside the types of the C# properties representing those columns (e. g. if you have an int property in C# representing a numeric column in the db with values > int.MaxValue or < int.MinValue)?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
My exception comes from oracle.dataaccess
and I think it happens because the number in the database has no scale, so there are 38 and it cannot be converted to decimal.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment on the question rather than an answer?